# How do I use pomegranate in-built functions

Tags: python, pomegranate

I am trying out a code from CS50 Artificial Intelligence course involving the use of pomegranate (a probability model). This is the code I ran:

```
from pomegranate import *

class Node():
    def __init__(self, distribution, name):
        self.distribution = distribution
        self.name = name

# Rain node has no parents
rain = Node(DiscreteDistribution({
    "none": 0.7,
    "light": 0.2,
    "heavy": 0.1
}), name="rain")

# Track maintenance node is conditional on rain
maintenance = Node(ConditionalProbabilityTable([
    ["none", "yes", 0.4],
    ["none", "no", 0.6],
    ["light", "yes", 0.2],
    ["light", "no", 0.8],
    ["heavy", "yes", 0.1],
    ["heavy", "no", 0.9]
], [rain.distribution]), name="maintenance")

# Train node is conditional on rain and maintenance
train = Node(ConditionalProbabilityTable([
    ["none", "yes", "on time", 0.8],
    ["none", "yes", "delayed", 0.2],
    ["none", "no", "on time", 0.9],
    ["none", "no", "delayed", 0.1],
    ["light", "yes", "on time", 0.6],
    ["light", "yes", "delayed", 0.4],
    ["light", "no", "on time", 0.7],
    ["light", "no", "delayed", 0.3],
    ["heavy", "yes", "on time", 0.4],
    ["heavy", "yes", "delayed", 0.6],
    ["heavy", "no", "on time", 0.5],
    ["heavy", "no", "delayed", 0.5],
], [rain.distribution, maintenance.distribution]), name="train")

# Appointment node is conditional on train
appointment = Node(ConditionalProbabilityTable([
    ["on time", "attend", 0.9],
    ["on time", "miss", 0.1],
    ["delayed", "attend", 0.6],
    ["delayed", "miss", 0.4]
], [train.distribution]), name="appointment")

# Create a Bayesian Network and add states
model = BayesianNetwork()
model.add_states(rain, maintenance, train, appointment)

# Add edges connecting nodes
model.add_edge(rain, maintenance)
model.add_edge(rain, train)
model.add_edge(maintenance, train)
model.add_edge(train, appointment)

# Finalize model
model.bake()
```

What I tried:

1. pip install pomegranate
2. Updated pip to the latest version

What I expect:

1. Able to run the code smoothly

What resulted:

1. [rain = Node(DiscreteDistribution({
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   NameError: name 'DiscreteDistribution' is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfJeG.png)

Even though DiscreteDistribution was stated as one of the functions in pomegranate's official website
Same goes to ConditionalProbabilityTable, and BayesianNetwork

Comment: May be related to the version of pomegranate you are using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77242084/2221001